# How to save yfinance data to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Okay so I'm trying to get all the information using yfinance, but the problem is that I'm not able to store all that data in a single file. My client wants me to get all the data for every stock, so I tried creating a program that allows you to enter a certain stock and get data.

```
def get_info_on_stock( ticker):
    stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    hist = stock.history(period = 'max')
    action = stock.actions
    dividend = stock.dividends
    financial = stock.financials
    qtr_financials = stock.quarterly_financials
    major_stake_holders = stock.major_holders
    institutional_holders = stock.institutional_holders
    df = print(stock, hist, action, dividend, financial, qtr_financials, major_stake_holders, 
    institutional_holders)
    df.actions.to_csv("data{}.csv")
```

can someone please help and guide me? I'm a beginner at this I could really use some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to save multiple dataframes in one single csv file. I strongly suggest to save multiple files instead.

First of all, your variables `action` and `dividend` are included in `hist`. So two files less to think about. In total you'll have:

```
# replace your last two lines with:
hist.to_csv(f"{ticker}_hist.csv")
financial.to_csv(f"{ticker}_financial.csv")
qtr_financials.to_csv(f"{ticker}_qtr_financials.csv")
major_stake_holders.to_csv(f"{ticker}_major_stake_holders.csv")
institutional_holders.to_csv(f"{ticker}_institutional_holders.csv")
```

But this is very unpractical. What you probably want to do is to easily manage multi-dimensions data. To do this I encourage you to look something like [python xArray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/getting-started-guide/why-xarray.html)